# Improve page loading speed

Tags: performance, pagespeed

I am the Founding Music Director of the non-profit Mozart Classical Orchestra and I am seeking a coding expert to clean mozartorchestra.org home page so it would load faster than the current 10"+. I would gladly trade concert tickets for the service. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You should not use the Mozart tag, because it is meant for the Mozart Programming System. Not for any name with Mozart in it.